# Ranking variable value in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with people with "ID" that has a procedure at a "date". I want to rank the procedures by date for each ID and create a "rank" variable that I can use in a GEE model.

I did:

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(my_rank = rank(date))
```

In the output, I see a "my_rank" variable, but when I do `df$my_rank` to see it, I have a `NULL` output. I need to have the rank variable value usable for modeling. The date is in `POSIX` format and I tried both with this format and a numerical one.

Thanks.

Comment: There is minor type `DF` and `df`??? Did you try `DF$my_rank` as your `data.frame` having name `DF`

Comment: You need to assign the output back to `df` (or `DF`?) if you want to modify `df`. Otherwise it will just create and print a new data.frame

Comment: Thank you. The DF is df. My real data.frame is dataTL.  Do I assign the whole line to the data.frame as: df$my_rank <- mutate(my_rank = rank(date)) or do I have to add df$my_rank instead of my_rank in the mutate argument ? Thank you.